# Stop Nginx rewrites breaking all pages following location block

Tags: nginx, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I'm having to rewrite URLs in nginx.conf that contain particular query parameters;

As an example:-

```
location /brands/exampleA {

    if ($arg_cat = "9") {
        return 301 /page/brand-filter;
    }

    if ($arg_cat = "38") {
        return 301 /page/category/brand-filter;
    }

}
```

These URL rewrites would then rewrite `example.com/brands/exampleA/?cat=9` to `example.com/page/brand-filter` and `example.com/brands/exampleA/?cat=38` to `example.com/page/category/brand-filter`.

And these work perfectly, but the problem is that they break every other child page of the location block so for example, the following pages would all not load with an Nginx error:-

```
example.com/brands/exampleA/range1
example.com/brands/exampleA/range2
example.com/brands/exampleA/range3
example.com/brands/exampleA/range4
```

So is there something I can add to the location statement to stop anything applying to anything after `exampleA` - these rewrites should ONLY match ?cat= query parameters.

Comment: To match only `/brands/exampleA/`, use `location = /brands/exampleA/`

Comment: Ah amazing, thanks @RichardSmith adding an = exactly fixed the issue. Add as answer if you want me to accept as solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration currently uses a *prefix location*, which means that it is considered when the requested URI **begins with** the value `/brands/exampleA`.

To restrict the match to only one URI, use the *exact match* syntax:

```
location = /brands/exampleA/ { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Cheers for the doc ref as well as I did try searching but wasn't sure what to search for really so did not come across this but that's ideal 